# Case insensitive string comparison in Go

Tags: string, go, string-comparison, equality, case-insensitive

How do I compare strings in a case insensitive manner?

For example, "Go" and "go" should be considered equal.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#EqualFold is the function you are looking for. It is used like this (example from the linked documentation):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.EqualFold("Go", "go"))
}
```

Comment: EqualFold not compare :(

Comment: Sorting can use strings.ToLower("Go") < strings.ToLower("go")

Comment: > EqualFold not compare 

@lunicon what do you mean?

Comment: @KBN, compare operation can say "more, less or equals", EqualFold retrun boolean

Answer (score 1):

There is alternative to `strings.EqualFold`, there is `bytes.EqualFold` which work in same way

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bytes.EqualFold([]byte("Go"), []byte("go")))
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#EqualFold

Comment: Please paste code as code, not as images.