# How to compare two string values in Go in a case insensitive manner?

Tags: string, go, comparison

How to compare two strings with case insensitivity?
For example: Both `"a" == "a"` and `"a" == "A"` must return `true`.

Comment: Convert them both to lower case, then compare.

Comment: what's the meaning of asking a question then answering it in less than 6 min ?

Comment: Must "ß" == "SS" also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive string search in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836044/case-insensitive-string-search-in-golang)

Answer (score 28):

There is a [`strings.EqualFold()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#EqualFold) function which performs case insensitive string comparison.

For example:

```
fmt.Println(strings.EqualFold("aa", "Aa"))
fmt.Println(strings.EqualFold("aa", "AA"))
fmt.Println(strings.EqualFold("aa", "Ab"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f0cdf0XFcD)):

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Note: assumes `utf-8`.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. Convert both strings to either lowercase or upper case and compare.

`import "strings"
strings.ToUpper(str1) == strings.ToUpper(str2)`

Comment: Converting strings to lowercase or uppercase only gives an approximately correct result - Unicode isn't this simple. Research the "Turkish i" problem for a starting point on diving down the rabbithole.

Answer (score -2):

strings.EqualFold() is not compare, some times you need sign of compare

```
func compareNoCase(i, j string) int {
    is, js := []rune(i), []rune(j)
    il, jl := len(is), len(js)

  ml := il
    if ml > jl {
        ml = jl
    }

    for n := 0; n < ml; n++ {
        ir, jr := unicode.ToLower(is[n]), unicode.ToLower(js[n])
        if ir < jr {
            return -1
        } else if ir > jr {
            return 1
        }
    }

    if il < jl {
        return -1
    }
    if il > jl {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func equalsNoCase(i, j string) bool {
    return compareNoCase(i, j) == 0
}
```